# Слово "окурок" - літературне?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zabrudnenyj) в словниковій статті "забруднений" натрапила на приклад, в якому використано слово "окурок":

> ЗАБРУ́ДНЕНИЙ, а, е. Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до забруднити. Підлога була забруднена **окурками** (Дмитро Бедзик, Дніпро.., 1951, 197)

Однак якщо шукати у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/okurok) слово "окурок", статті не вибиває.

Отож слово "окурок" все-таки літературне чи ні?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оскільки тут розглядаємо лиш літературність сучасної мови, то слово справді виходить **нелітературним**. Наголошу, тут розлядаємо саме питання літературности, а не „ізмости“.

Літературність визначається словниками і лиш поважними, котрих я й наведу:

- Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)
- Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)
- Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)
- Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич)
- Правописний словник 1929р. (Г. Голоскевич)
- Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)
- Українсько-англійський словник 1955р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет)
- Словник української мови в 11 книгах: [*недокурок*](http://sum.in.ua/s/nedokurok), розм. [*бичок*](http://sum.in.ua/s/bychok)

**Всі** вони раять [*недокур*](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)/[*ок*](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), декотрі ще *бичок*, але не [*окурок*](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&highlight=on). Також особисто бачив сміттєвик з знаком „для недопалків“, теє слово може вважатися літературним, оскільки СУМ‑11 має слова [*недопалок*](http://sum.in.ua/s/nedopalok).

Answer (score -1):

Слова **окурок** немає в українській мові. На підтвердження цього у [Російсько-українському словнику](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53406/164151.html):

> **ОКУРОК** 
>   недокур, недокурок, бичок (-чка).

Також у ще одному [Російсько-українському словнику](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/ru-uk/word-okurki-translation#):

> **Окурки** – недопалки.

Отже, **окурок** – не є літературним.

Comment: Щоб робити висновок, що слово є запозиченим з іншої мови чи ні, потрібно досліджувати етимологію слова, а те, що це слово перекладається з російської, не є підставою, щоб визачати це слово як росіянізм. Наприклад, слово "курити" було ще у старослов'янській та інших слов'янських мовах.
----------
[Один](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/ru-uk/word-okurki-translation#) із словників, на які ви посилаєтесь у своєму заголовку має "... на українській мові". Це, на мою думку, уже ставить під сумнів, чи варто ним користуватися.